# How to change the style applied by the framework only for a particular component using Module CSS?

Tags: css, reactjs, styles, devextreme, css-modules

I want to change the style of a commonly used component whose style is applied by framework, only in one case (component). I'm using Devextreme as framework with React JS.
I can mutate the corresponding class (`.dx-texteditor.dx-editor-filled::after`) in browser Inspect. Changing the style of the class in the main CSS or any other CSS file will be applied to all similar components. Also, if I use `module.css`, it doesn't work because I don't apply the class myself (It is applied by framework). What is the best way to change the style of such a class only for a specific component?

Answer (score 0):

What is `module.css`? I'm going to assume it's your own CSS file...

I don't know if it will help, but the application of a style sheet depends on the order given in the page.

So your CSS file should be placed after that of DevExtreme's CSS files, if I'm not mistaken.

This means that you should therefore obtain an order like this:

```html
<head>
   <!-- ... -->

   <!-- DevExtreme -->
    <link rel="dx-theme" data-theme="generic.light" href="css/dx.light.css" data-active="false">
    <link rel="dx-theme" data-theme="generic.light.compact" href="css/dx.light.compact.css" data-active="false">

   <!-- Customs CSS -->
    <link href="css/module.css" />
</head>
```

The 2nd solution to test, but which I do not recommend at all, is to put `!important` after your CSS properties:

```css
.dx-texteditor.dx-editor-filled::after {
   color: red !important;
}
```

Otherwise you have to go through your own CSS class and add it to the DevExtreme component.

**I specify that I have not tested these solutions, but these are some leads that I can give you**

Comment: module.css is not my own css file. In React because of the structure of page rendering, css classes can affect other classes with same name. Fot example if file one with css file named one.css has a class style for a div wirh name design and file two has the same class with no css file imported, all divs in file two with class named design, get the style from one.css. On the other word, in React if you have same classes name in several files even with no css imported, the intrupt each other. The solution is using .module.css extension instead of css extension for styling file.

Comment: My problem solved by this solution: https://dhanrajsp.me/snippets/css-module-going-global-with-class-selectors